# iTunes cannot locate missing files after I've moved them to a USB

Tags: itunes, usb, music

I've been using iTunes on Mac for a while, but my startup disk recently got pretty close to being full so I figured I'd move all my music I had there from the iTunes Media folder to my USB drive. However, after I've gone through and set the folder location to my USB's music folder, about 2,000 of my more recently downloaded songs have gone missing. Choosing to use a song's location to determine the location of other songs just tells me it can't locate any of the missing songs, even though all albums are in their own folder with all the files either named "1-01 song name, 1-02 song name etc." or "1 song name, 2 song name etc.".

I could go through and manually locate all of them, but I just can't do that when there are almost 2,000 songs missing. So I ask, is there a way I can somehow get all the files back into iTunes without having to manually locate every one?

Comment: How did you move and what options did you set in iTunes. iTunes has an option under Preferences > Advanced that let you set the location of the library but you have to move the ENTIRE iTunes library.

Answer (score 1):

do a search for your files, and in a finder window, drag them to the following directory where your iTunes file is located:

iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes

This will process them and put them back in your iTunes library.
You can move directories containing files as well, you do not need to sort your folders before, but if you don't like the way that iTunes automatically organize your files on import, you would have to reorganize.